# MySQL spiliting table

Tags: mysql, percona

My application developed using mysql & java, it's for hospital management system, i have one table hold all charges for patient - X-rays, Lab tests, Medications, surgeries ... etc.
since the number of transactions will be so high, i'm thinking of split this table to smaller ones, so i have each charges type in it's won table.
is this better for performance & management?

Comment: For performance perhaps, depending on your queries, but for management probably not. Creating a new charge type would require you to create new tables, and finding all charges on a patient would require multiple queries or some kind of mega-join with all charge tables.

Comment: Aha, i have all charges in one table called HospitalCharges, which include the pricing, departments...etc. the major issue for me is when patient get covered by insurance company these companies has a contract with hospital with special prices, for that i did a contract module. do you have any document or examples for manage these cases? i need to know the best design that i can get to assure integrity, performance ... etc.